# Google Maps Geocoder not giving results

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using jQuery with the Google Maps API V3's Geocoder. The site user enters a location in the textbox and clicks on the submit button, which calls the code below to geocode the address given by the user into LatLng coordinates.

```
$(function(){

$("#searchbox_form #search_button").click(function(){
    var address = $("#location").val();

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    alert(address);
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        alert("123");
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            $("#user_lat").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat);
            $("#user_lng").val(results[0].geometry.location.lng);
            alert("lat: " + $("#user_lat").val());
            alert("lng: " + $("#user_lat").val());
        } else {
            alert("asdasdasd");
            alert(status);  
        }
    }); 
});
```

});

However there is some problem. You will notice I placed several `alert()`s in the code. When 'Boston' is entered into the textbox and the submit button is clicked, only `alert("address");` is executed showing `Boston` but `alert("123")` does not run. **Did something go wrong somewhere?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to disable the submitting of the form :)

Answer (score 0):

Check in any web - debugger whether any request is even made or not?

The code seems fine to me.